# Running an iPython notebook server on an EC2 Ubuntu instance via Docker

Tags: ubuntu, networking, amazon-ec2, ipython, docker

I am trying to run an iPython notebook server via Docker on an EC2 Ubuntu instance. I have enabled all incoming HTTP connections on port 80, SSH connections on port 22 and custom TCP connections on port 8888.

I installed docker using

`sudo apt-get install docker.io`

Then I pulled the ipython/notebook repository

`sudo docker pull ipython/scipyserver`

However, I am unable to deploy the notebook. I tried

```
sudo docker run -d -p 54.187.44.99:8888:8888 -e "PASSWORD=<your password>" ipython/scipyserver
```

where 54.187.44.99 is the public IP of my aws ec2 instance.

This gives me the following error -

```
2014/09/17 17:00:09 Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 5c9e1f998606d90b93a2652e9998373c3a200e3cf2f219bb8f5c4e03f429bfdc: port has already been allocated
```

However, the port 8888 is not being used on the host machine. I used netstat to verify this.

Could someone more knowledgeble please guide me where I am going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What does `docker ps` output? Is there another container using this port?

Comment: @MarcusHughes - Nope, this is the only container. I already checked that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to listen on **0.0.0.0** because if the ec2 instance is inside a vpc you will not be able to see the public ip in the network interface list.

```
sudo docker run -d -p 0.0.0.0:8888:8888 -e "PASSWORD=<your password>" ipython/scipyserver
```

or simply...

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8888:8888 -e "PASSWORD=<your password>" ipython/scipyserver
```